# SignalR proxy client undefined on javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Here is my SignalR Hub class

```
  [HubName("LyncHub")]
    public class LyncHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly LyncPresenceChecker _lyncpresenceChecker;

        public LyncHub() : this(LyncPresenceChecker.Instance) { }

        public LyncHub(LyncPresenceChecker checker)
        {
            _lyncpresenceChecker = checker;
        }
        [HubMethodName("getAllUsers")]
        public IEnumerable<LyncUser> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return _lyncpresenceChecker.GetAllUsers();
        }
    }
```

Here is the javascript code where I am calling the proxy of the hub.

```
var checker = $.connection.lyncHub,  //generated client side proxy hub
    available = 'available',
    busy = 'busy',
    $presenceTable = $('lyncPresence'),
    $presenceBody = $('#Maintable > tbody'),
    rowTemplate = '<tr id="{Id}"><td><div class="{Status} status"></div></td><td><div>{Name}</td></tr>';
console.log("value of checker " + checker);
function formatPresence(lyncUser) {
    return $.extend(lyncUser, {
        Name: lyncUser.UserName,
        Status: lyncUser.Presence,
        Id: lyncUser.UserName.replace(' ','-')
    });
}
```

------- Updated javascript --------

```
 var connection = $.hubConnection();

    var checker = connection.createHubProxy('lyncHub'),  //generated client side proxy hub
        available = 'available',
        busy = 'busy',
        $presenceTable = $('lyncPresence'),
        $presenceBody = $('#Maintable > tbody'),
        rowTemplate = '<tr id="{Id}"><td><div class="{Status} status"></div></td><td><div>{Name}</td></tr>';
    console.log("value of checker " + checker);
```

---

The above javascript code is called from my main html file like so

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="LyncChecker.js"></script>
```

The issue I am having is that when the browser executes the following line

```
var checker = $.connection.lyncHub
```

checker is undefined.

My startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

please help.

---

### Update

So i got the connection working but it terminates prematurely. See logs

```
http://localhost:65119/~/signalr/hubs Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js:24 [15:51:01 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'lynchub'.
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js:24 [15:51:01 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22lynchub%22%7D%5D'.
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23 GET http://localhost:65119/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22lynchub%22%7D%5D&_=1457067060600 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23x.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23i.transports._logic.ajax @ jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js:24r.fn.r.start @ jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js:24a._.deferredStartHandler @ jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js:24x.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22v.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js:24 [15:51:01 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.
```

Comment: Any 404 errors or other HTTP anomalies in the page load?  Have you tried using the developer tools on your browser (F12 for most common browsers) to examine the loaded scripts and check on the `$.connection` object?

Comment: <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script> is not loading 500 0KB

Comment: Something wrong with the SignalR config at the server side then.  Try removing the `HubName` attribute.  Also look into your server logs for anything to do with exceptions or other reasons for the 500 response.,